# react router with dynamic routes give 404 on a browser direct link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-router-v4

I have a `React` Front-end connected to `Wordpress API` and the routes are defined in clientside with `React Router`. When i use `Link` to direct them to dynamic routes they work fine. But when i use browser address bar directly to access the links pressing enter, or i refresh.i get

> 404 page not found

and i got to know that is because a direct call to server is happening and the there's no `javascript` to manipulate the `react-router` actions on the shared host when we have a `PHP Server` on that.

Thought about `react-snapshot` but its not going to suit the dynamic nature from the API.Please can anyone i give a possible way to go around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out: https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages

The concept might help you.

> When the GitHub Pages server gets a request for a path defined with frontend routes, e.g. example.tld/foo, it returns a custom 404.html page. The custom 404.html page contains a script that takes the current url and converts the path and query string into just a query string, and then redirects the browser to the new url with only a query string and hash fragment.

Comment: what is the solution?