# 404 issue with a React Project deployed with Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, github, react-router

I finished a React project, but when I deployed it with Github Pages, I have a 404 issue,

**The URL of the online project is here : https://versifiction.github.io/api-ratp/**

When we go on it, we are redirected on the 404 page that I made with React-Router (component of the routing : **https://github.com/Versifiction/api-ratp/blob/master/src/App.js**),

I think we are redirected to the 404 because the "/api-ratp" in the URL is not declared in the routes, but if I want to deploy this project with Github Pages I have to use the Github repository name on the URL,

Is there a way to change the basepath of the project or something ?
Someone knows how can I resolve this ? Thank you !

**Edit: I solved the issue by adding the prop "basename" to the Router**

Comment: your page opens for me

Comment: yes I just solved the issue, I added the prop "basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}" to the Router component, thanks

Comment: You will get the 404 again if you reload a page when in a route. See https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react router with dynamic routes give 404 on a browser direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44733730/react-router-with-dynamic-routes-give-404-on-a-browser-direct-link)